# Swagger - Inject string into IOperationFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, swagger

I am having an OperationFilter which needs a string to work

```
    public class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter(string scope)
        {
            Scope = scope;
        }

        public string Scope { get; }

        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            // Here is the Scope needed
        }
    }
```

and the Swaggergen in Startup:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc(apiVersion, new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = apiName,
        Version = apiVersion,
    });

    ...

    options.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>();
});
```

The Problem is, that Swagger cannot resolve the `AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter` because there is no string registered

[image]

I also tried to register the `AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter` with a given String, but this also won't work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding your filter, you'll need to pass the parameter as well like this:

```
options.OperationFilter<AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter>("myScope");
```

Tested an verified on my computer.

Comment: Yes, this works.. I can also provide a List of scopes or any other object. I wasn't sure, for what the params were used for, but this answers my question :D Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to wrap the string in some object. For example, if the string needs to be configurable, you could wrap it in an options object like this. (If not, you could just as easily create a POCO to hold your string, and register it with the DI container.)

**appsettings.json**

```json
{
  "AuthorizationOptions": {
    "Scope": "myScope"
  }
}
```

**AuthorizationOptions.cs**

```cs
public class AuthorizationOptions
{
  public string Scope { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
services.Configure<AuthorizationOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AuthorizationOptions)));
```

**AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter.cs**

```cs
public class AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
  private readonly string scope;
  
  public AuthorizeCheckOperationFilter(IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> authorizationOptions)
  {
    this.scope = authorizationOptions.Value.Scope;
  }
  
  // rest of your implementation...
}
```